# iFrame Transperancy over PDF in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

I have a requirement to set transperancy to the modal popup over pdf. Now every thing works well in Google Chrome but as Internet Explorer is widely used Browser all the over the world, I wanna make it work in IE as well.

As you can see in the screenshot 1, I have a modal popup over pdf which looks beautiful.

[image: ScreenShot 1]

Now see the screenshot 2 when i set transperancy to modal popup its totally become whitish.

[image: ScreenShot 2]

Now see the screenshot 3 its working properly in Chrome which is exactly what i want to behave same in Internet Explorer.

[image: ScreenShot 3]

I am setting transperancy using Jquery library here is the code

```
$("#pnlSpecialInstructions").fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
$("#iFrameSplIns").fadeTo("slow", 0.5);
```

I have tried using IE Filters as well but its not working.... :(

[image]

If anyone want to see what i have tried till now you can check from this fiddle link : [Click Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rickjackson/7K6vG/3/)

Comment: _May_ have something to do with Chrome's internal PDF viewer vs. IE's use of the plugin?

Comment: Yeah HIS thanks for your reply afer googling around I have found that Google Chrome has its internal pdf viewer and the IE depends on Adobe or any other plugin so now the question is how can i make the popup transperant over pdf... in IE ?

Comment: I don't know how to do this with the plugin; I doubt it is possible. Plugins and transparency just don't mix well as plugins live in a different OS graphic and semantic context, outside the browser display engine. Transparency would be a dramatic performance killer. Maybe you could do it with pdf.js as this displays PDF inside the browser engine.

Comment: Which IE are you using? There's a big difference between IE6 and IE9, for example...

Comment: Hey ord and HIS thanks for ur reply again... I am using IE 10 and IE 8 ...

Answer (score -1):

Could a IE filter help maybe ? Here is an old reference from css-tricks... I don't know where it would fit in... but might be a direction to think about.

```
.transparent_class {
  /* IE 8 */
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

  /* IE 5-7 */
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);

  /* Netscape */
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Safari 1.x */
  -khtml-opacity: 0.5;

  /* Good browsers */
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this as well but this is not working... :(

Comment: Shouldn't be needed at all as you are using jQuery - one of its USPs is to abstract from such hacks.

Answer (score -1):

Add allowtransparency="true" attribute in iFrame tag and check the result.

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" src="<Your URL>"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hey Manikandan thanks for your reply... I have tried that as well but its not working... :(